# Limit of the recurrent sequence $a_{n+1} = (1 + a_n + a^2_{n−1})/4$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Let $a_0 = a_1 = 1$. For $n = 1, 2, \cdots $ define $a_{n+1} = (1 + a_n + a^2_{n−1})/4$. Does the sequence $\{a_n\}$ converge to a finite limit as $n → ∞$? Find the limit if it does.

My approach : It is easy to show $\{a_n\}$ is bounded by $1$. I tried to show that the sequence is monotone decreasing. Then using Bolzano Weirstrass theorem it follows the sequence is convergent. But I cannot show the sequence is monotone. Using induction I could show, $a_{n+1} \leq a_{n-1}$. How to show $a_{n+1} \leq a_n$ as well. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If it converges to $c$, then $c=(1+c+c^2)/4$.

Comment: Yes, but first I need to show the existence. Only then I can use this relation.

Comment: I know that. I helped you with part of your problem. Perhaps someone else will help you with the other part. Meanwhile, you could thank me.

Comment: Oh. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

First, let $c = (3-\sqrt{5})/2 < 1$, which is a solution to $c = (1+c+c^2)/4 \Longleftrightarrow c^2 - 3c + 1 = 0$. The other solution is denoted by $d = (3+\sqrt{5})/2 > 1$.

Consider the following mathematical (strong) induction:

1)
$$
a_0 \geq a_1 \geq c
$$

2. Suppose
   $$
   a_0 \geq a_1 \ldots \geq a_n \geq c
   $$
3. Show
   $$
   a_0 \geq a_1 \ldots \geq a_n \geq a_{n+1} \geq c
   $$

First, $a_n \geq a_{n+1}$ can be shown as
$$
a_{n+1} = (1 + a_n + a_{n-1}^2)/4 \leq a_n \Longleftrightarrow
1 + a_{n-1}^2 \leq 3 a_n \implies 1+a_{n-1}^2 \leq 3a_{n-1} \Longleftrightarrow a_{n-1}^2 - 3a_{n-1} + 1 \leq 0
$$
since $c \leq a_{n-1} \leq 1 < d$ (as you mentioned, $a_n$'s are less or equal to one).

Next,
$$
a_{n+1} = (1+a_n + a_{n-1}^2)/4 \geq (1+c+c^2)/4 = c
$$
, which implies the induction is true.

Then, it is easy to show that $c = \lim_{n \to \infty} a_n$.

Comment: Thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 1):

I think I got it let me know if you find any errors.
Basically what's left for you is only to prove the sequence is monotone decreasing.
Let's use complete induction:

base case : $ n=1 $

$ a_2 \leq 1+a_1+a_0^2 $ this is true since since $a_n$ is bounded by 1 as you've mentioned

hypothesis:
true $ \forall n \in \mathbb{N} :  ( 1 \leq n \leq n+1)  $ so

$a_{n+1} \leq a_n \leq a_{n-1}$

proof: $a_{n+2} \leq a_n+1 $

$a_{n+2} = (1 + a_{n+1} + a_n^2)/4 $

$ 4 a_{n+2} = (1 + a_{n+1} + a_n^2) \leq 1+ a_n +a_{n-1}^2 = 4a_{n+1} $
here we use the hypothesis for $ a_{n+1}$ and $a_n$

thus $ a_{n+2} \leq a_{n+1} $

hope it helps! finished calculus course so I'm pretty confident it's true if there are any errors then I deeply apologize

Comment: Wow! I think it's very nice solution. Thanks.

Comment: Glad it helps! You're welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Since the sequence is positive, if we show that it is decreasing it will also be bounded, in fact $a_n \in (0,a_1] = (0,1]$. Being bounded and monotone, the sequence is convergent and the limit, $L$, must satisfy $L = \frac 14(1+L+L^2)$, i.e. $L = \frac{3-\sqrt{5}}{2}$.

Using induction, we just need to show that $a_1 \leq a_0, a_1 \leq a_2$ and that if the sequence is decreasing up to the term $(n+1)$, it will also be decreasing up to the term $(n+2)$. In fact,
$$
a_{n+2}-a_{n+1} = \frac 14(a_{n+1}+a_n^2 - a_n - a_{n-1}^2) = \frac 14 (\underbrace{(a_{n+1}-a_n)}_{\leq 0} + \underbrace{(a_n+a_{n-1})}_{>0}\underbrace{(a_n-a_{n-1})}_{\leq 0}) \leq 0.
$$